# CSS not selector not working?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, css-selectors

I am using Javascript to create a table, and each td has a column and row class. For example, the first, top left most td has two classes, .row0 and .column0. Here is the line of code which create the clases:

```
theTr.append($("<td>", { "class": "row"+h + " column"+i,
                         html: heights[h][i]
                       }));
```

where `h` and `i` are variables which increment. Ignoring the

```
html: heights[h][i]
```

part, you can see that each td's class is similar to this format

```
<td class="rowh columni">
```

Now, I want all td's in the first row to have a background color of blue and font color of white. To do this, I did

```
.row0 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

which works perfectly. I also want each td in column0 (except for the td which is on .row0) to have a font color of red. So I tried

```
.column0:not(.row0) {
    color: red;
}
```

but this doesn't work, it doesn't make any changes to any font color. I know, I can just use the

```
!important
```

tag on the td with .column0 .row0 and I know there are other ways of doing it but is there a way of doing it with the :not selector? Note that I am using IE8 and CSS, not CSS3.Am I using the :not selector correctly?

Comment: `:not()` isn't supported in IE8.

Comment: `:not()` is CSS3, so you cannot expect it to work everywhere.

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#search=not supports begins in IE9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 does not support the :not selector

Comment: Ah man, okay then. I guess I will just use the !important tag.

Comment: @user2719875 - you could use a JS tool like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to polyfill support for CSS3 selectors. That will help you support for `:not()` (and other selectors) to IE8.